# Stylus writing conversion in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice

Hello thanks for taking the time to answer my question. But, I already run Ubuntu 18.4 on my Sony  Vaio which I dual boot Widows & Ubuntu. I am familiar with installing linux. my question related to my Samsung tablet, I would like to run it solely with Ubuntu but am unsure if the features I require will be available. at present using Windows, I can hand write into Libre office, I need to know if I will be able to do the same if I convert from W8.1 to Ubuntu. Thanks

Comment: It is not clear from your question whether you are asking about a **tablet computer** (ie, Android, Tizen, etc, tablet) which has an application that can recognise and convert your handwriting to text, or whether you are asking about a **graphics tablet input device** which you use to handwrite on your computer directly, and then want to convert the handwriting to text. Could you please edit your question to clarify further what you are asking about?

Answer (score 1):

You can try Ubuntu on your computer before installing by using a live USB stick. Refer to [this article](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started) for instructions on how to try Ubuntu without installing. Note that speeds when booting off of a live USB stick will be slower than when Ubuntu is installed. Check and see if your keyboard with Libreoffice works and if it does, install Ubuntu!

Comment: Hello thanks for taking the time to answer my question. But, I already run Ubuntu 18.4 on my Sony  Vaio which I dual boot Widows & Ubuntu. I am familiar with installing linux. my question related to my Samsung tablet, I would like to run it solely with Ubuntu but am unsure if the features I require will be available. At present using Windows, I am able to 'hand write' into Libre office, I need to know if I will be able to do the same if I convert from W8.1 to Ubuntu. Thanks